# Double summation proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Prove that the sum of all the numbers in the triangular table
$$
a(1,1)\\
a(2,1) a(2,2)\\
a(3,1) a(3,2) a(3,3)\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
a(m,1) a(m,2) a(m,3)......a(m,m)\\
$$
can be expressed as $$\sum_{i = 1}^m \sum_{j = 1}^ i a(i,j) $$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you  tried writing out the sums for $m=3$, for example, to see what is happening?

Comment: I did try the sum out and expanded the notation for the first sigma. But after that I’m not able to proceed.

Comment: You want to see how the $m=3$ case generates the same six things to add as are in the triangle.  Did you observe that?  It should be clear how the indices work to make that happen.

Comment: No sir, I'm new to learn this concept. Can you please elaborate. it will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $m=3$ the outer sum has three terms.  The inner sum has $i$ terms.  When $i=3$ the inner sum gives $a(3,1)+a(3,2)+a(3,3)$ which is exactly row $3$ of your table.  Having seen this you should be able to convince yourself that the inner sum always gives row $i$ of the table, so the outer sum gives the sum of the whole triangle through row $m$.

Comment: now I got it. thank you, sir.